# Print a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an astrophysic project by using data file. It's a csv data file.

I'm using the following code in Python :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np

# Fichier contenant le champ 169 #

file = '/astromaster/home/xxx/Bureau/Stage/Champs/Field_169/Field169_combined_final_roughcal.csv'

        ###############################
        # Lecture du fichier field169 #
        ###############################

field169 = np.loadtxt(fname = file, 
          dtype = [('ID',object), 
               ('RA','f10'), 
               ('DEC','f10'), 
                   ('NDET','i2'), 
                   ('DEPTHFAG','i2'),
                   ('SEPINDX',object),
                   ('SEPFINDX',object),
                   ('U','f10'),
                   ('UERR','f10'),
                   ('G','f10'),
                   ('GERR','f10'),
                   ('R','f10'),
                   ('RERR','f10'),
                   ('I','f10'),
                   ('IERR','f10'),
                   ('Z','f10'),
                   ('ZERR','f10'),
                   ('CHI','f10'),
                   ('SHARP','f10'),
                   ('FLAG','i3'),
                   ('PROB','f10'),
                   ('EBV','f10')],
            delimiter=",")


print field169
```

But, when I print this array, I just have half of my array .. and I don't understand why ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Set [print options](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) before printing:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this solution doesn't seem to work. After 10 min, none array was printed :/

Comment: Your array could be really big. Try increasing the threshold gradually (first 10000, then 100000 etc)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set print options with [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).
Try:

```
 import numpy as np
 np.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
 print np.arange(10000)
```

it will print the full 10000 dimension array.

Comment: Ok I undertstand my problem. I've a csv file where each colomn are separated by the coma "," but in 2 colomns, data inside are also separated by coma. So when I use np.loadtxt (delimiter=","), the problem is that

Comment: FInally, the problem is not this one. As I said just before, it's a delimiter problem in my csv file :/

Comment: if the array is very large, it will not show the full array with `print` without `np.set_printoptions`

Comment: Yes I understand, but my problem is before the print xD
My problem is in the construction of my array with the separate coma